# How to restructure object to array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have this object

```
var data = {
         _id : 131233442543,
         SocialMedia_0__Name_: "facebook",
         SocialMedia_0__URL_: "http://facebook.com/test",
         SocialMedia_1__Name_: "twitter",
         SocialMedia_1__URL_: "http://twitter.com/test",
         SocialMedia_1398083781749__Name_: "linkedin",
         SocialMedia_1398083781749__URL_: "http://linkedin.com/test"
        };
```

And I need to restructure the object to be like this:

```
justSites = [
{
name : "facebook",
url : "http://facebook.com/test"
},
{
name : "twitter",
url : "http://twitter.com/test"
},
{
name : "linkedin",
url : "http://linkedin.com/test"
}
];
```

Comment: This indexes in names (0, 1, 1398083781749) are serial, with no holes?

Comment: Yes, but there are some other keys and i need just sites

Comment: You need to parse it, loop, then push into a new object and encode it to json, what language are you using?

Comment: Does the array need to be in the same order as the property "indices"?

Comment: The main problem here will be to find max index to iterate through object keys. Since you have some other keys than name/url, you can't just count it and divide by 2. The only thing you can do, **if data itself don't contain its length**, is to match each key with regex, get index and push to new array data based on this indexes.

Comment: Please note that this has **nothing** to do with JSON, at all. What you have is a JavaScript object and you seem to want to restructure it into an array of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var justSites = [], m;
for (var p in data)
    if (m = p.match(/SocialMedia_(\d+)__Name_/))
        justSites.push({
            name: data[p],
            url: data["SocialMedia_"+m[1]+"__URL_"]
        });
```